# Generalized Hyperbolic and Circular Functions

Tags: analysis, reference-request, special-functions

I have recently posted a couple of questions in regards to Generalized Hyperbolic and Circular Functions and I was hoping to find a couple more papers available on the particular subject.  The papers I have found are

[Beyond Sin and Cos](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691389?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Muldoon and Ungar

[Generalized Hyperbolic Functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910143) by Muldoon

[On generalized hyperbolic functions and their characterization by functional equations](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01835702) By Schwaiger (I have not read this one as I can't find a pdf online and am not a member).

I have scrolled through the references of the first two and gotten a couple of tidbits, but if anyone can point me in the direction of more papers or research, that would be very helpful